# setting variables from a common python script

Tags: python

I often write scripts for plotting in Python, and I often want to use common settings for the graph including line weights and colors etc.

Currently I copy and paste all these variables at the start of the file e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
company_color_1 = "#40A7E8"
company_color_2 = "#707070"
marker_width = 2.5


# my script here:
plt.plot(x, y, color=company_color_1)
```

What I want to achieve is that I can just put one same line at the start of each script instead such as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
my_graph_settings()

# script:
plt.plot(x, y, color=company_color_1)
```

so that I can control everything from one file and manage changes better.

How would I go about this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think about doing it as an `import` statement, where you import a file that has these variables defined within it.

For example:

```
import graph_config as config
```

And in that file, `graph_config.py`, define the properties you want to reference:

```
company_color_1 = "#40A7E8"
company_color_2 = "#707070"
```

Then in your script, you can reference the properties of that object:

```
plt.plot(x, y, color=config.company_color_1)
```

You can even make a `dict` of a few properties if that's useful for controlling other appearances of the plot.

Answer (score 4):

Make a Python file called `my_graph_settings.py` with the variables you want, and then import it. If you're okay with potential naming conflicts and want to use each variable as if it was defined in the current script, you can import everything into the current namespace:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from my_graph_settings import *

# script:
plt.plot(x, y, color=company_color_1)
```

But it'd be better to alias it so you don't pollute the namespace:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import my_graph_settings as mgs

# script:
plt.plot(x, y, color=mgs.company_color_1)
```